# Plotting a calculated value in pyplot

Tags: python, text, matplotlib

I have calculated few values, say p1=3.5 and p2=4.5 (I am only giving sample values here). They both are numpy objects. Now I need to use these values in my pyplot.

I tried

```
plt.text(0.0,0.0,'c for 13.6<M_{200}<13.7 =',p1)
```

but I get an error saying **AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'items'**

I am using Python 2.6 and I have also tried it with **plt.figtext**, but I am not able to use the calculated values.

I know that I can rather say `plt.text(0.0,0.0,'c for 13.6<M_{200}<13.7 =3.5')` which will give me the desired output, but I need to do this for many values!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the full string beforehand

```
plt.text(0.0, 0.0, 'c for 13.6<M_{200}<13.7 = %g' % p1)
```

Here, I used the [old string formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) to avoid escaping the brackets.
With the [new string formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting), the same line would read

```
plt.text(0.0, 0.0, 'c for 13.6<M_{{200}}<13.7 = {}'.format(p1))
```

There also is an interesting [thread on SO on string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5082452/932593).